# Valor que previo en selectionChange() - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

quería saber si hay alguna manera de capturar el valor que había antes seleccionado en un `<mat-select>` con el `(selectionChange)="removeOption($event.value)"`

`Value` solo me devuelve el valor actual, pero necesito saber cuál estaba anteriormente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable auxiliar en el componente para guardar el valor previo. En cada `change` guardar el valor actual en la variable auxiliar y luego setear el nuevo valor.

Entiendo que tendrás una variable para hacer el binding del valor seleccionado al `mat-select`. Para poner el ejemplo, he llamado a la variable `selectedValue`

En tu componente

```
selectedValue = 1;
prevValue;
removeOption(newValue) {
   // antes de hacer asignar el nuevo guardamos el valor actual en la variable auxiliar
   this.prevValue = this.selectedValue;
   // se asigna el nuevo valor 
   this.selectedValue = newValue;
}
```

[Aquí tienes una demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dvumpx). Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gacias!!

Comment: si te sirvió acepta la respuesta please. Dale al check. Gracias